# How do I write a shell script to fetch a value from key:value pair in the text file?

Tags: shell

I have a text file for example

```
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port: 123
```

How do I write a linux shell script that would give me the value based on the server_ip key.

**Sample File**

```
[LOGGER]
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port:123
#many such blocks as shown above
```

Comment: [LOGGER]
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port:123     this is the file content..  Many thanks.  There are various such blocks in the file.   My script needs first look for the LOGGER and then pick the ip address associated with server_port key,,   what modifications will be needed pls?.. Apologies for not stating the query completely.

Comment: What `value` are you looking for?

Comment: thanks.  I wanted to assign to a variable for further processing.  Looks like I am able to include awk statement in the  var=$(..) . that seem to work.  Need to try further.

Answer (score 2):

### Answers for original question

#### Using awk:

```
$ awk '/^server_ip/ {print $2}' file
1.1.1.1
```

This selects any line that begins with `server_ip` and prints the second field on that line.

#### Using sed:

```
$ sed -n 's/server_ip: //p' file
1.1.1.1
```

This attempts to remove `server_ip:` from a line and only prints output for those lines for which the substitution succeeds.

#### Using `grep -P` (requires GNU grep):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=server_ip: ).*' file
1.1.1.1
```

This uses a Perl-style look-behind to select text which follows `server_ip:`.

### Answers for revised question

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat file
[GOG]
server_ip: 2.2.2.2
server_port: 123
[LOGGER]
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port: 123
[FOG]
server_ip: 3.3.3.3
server_port: 123
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/LOGGER/,/^server_ip/{if (/^server_ip/) print $2}' file
1.1.1.1
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed -n '/LOGGER/,/^server_ip/{s/server_ip: //p}' file
1.1.1.1
```

#### Assigning output to a variable

Output that appears on stdout on the screen can be captured to a variable using *command substitution* which looks like `$(...)`.    Thus:

```
ip="$(awk '/^server_ip/ {print $2}' file)"
```

Or:

```
ip="$(sed -n 's/server_ip: //p' file)"
```

Or:

```
ip="$(grep -oP '(?<=server_ip: ).*' file)"
```

Comment: thanks .  I fogot to mention   the file format is like this:

Comment: thanks. this works great in terms of picking desired values however I am not able to assign it to a variable in my script for further processing....   What would be the way to address this?

Comment: @saee Assigning to a variable is done with _command substitution_.  I updated the answer with several examples.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not immensely clear. If you were looking for the port based on the ip, you would have used a small script for the purpose.
**Input**

```
$ cat file
[GOG]
server_ip: 2.2.2.2
server_port: 123
[LOGGER]
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port: 123
[FOG]
server_ip: 3.3.3.3
server_port: 123
```

**Script**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
echo "Usage : command server_name"
exit 1
fi
sed -n "/$1/{n;N;p;q}" file
```

**On Running**

```
$ ./script LOGGER
server_ip: 1.1.1.1
server_port: 123
```

Comment: @mona_sax Sorry, I didn't quite understand what the op meant. Please see the update.